# Lag between BigQuery Storage Write API and Read API

Tags: google-bigquery

When I inserted data using Storage Write API and tried to access using Storage Read API, it takes for a while until the data become available. If I use BigQuery Web UI or JDBC driver, I can access the data immediately. How can I achieve it with Storage Read API?

Comment: Are you using the `Committed` or `Pending` mode to write data. What you express here is that probably from using the pending mode to write. Switch to committed and should work. If not, create a support ticket as this sounds like a bug of the region/area your project is assigned too.

Comment: I tried both mode, but even `Committed` didn't work. Thank you for your suggestion. I will create a support ticket.

Comment: Could you provide some overview of the process? Do you have lag when you are writing, reading or both? From where you are saving this data to BigQuery? Which documentation have you followed? How long is this lag 15 seconds, 1 minute or more?

Comment: No lag for writing. I can access the data (written by Storage Write API) immediately if I use BigQuery web console or JDBC driver. I followed https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api for write api. The lag is more than 15 minutes.

Comment: Filed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200589932

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is correct for now. Data written by the BigQuery Storage Write API cannot be immediately queried with the Read API. But this feature is going to come out soon. Keep an eye out!